# How to recover social share counts in ShareThis.com after changing permalink

Tags: web, window

I just change my domain from http: to https: . Something has change on ShareThis buttons. So, the facebook Like buttons has been reset to 0. But the Share buttons are still intact.

So, I want to recover those Likes.

Answer (score 0):

I discover 2 solution. Add one of the solution to website, this will show the old Likes. Just change `webpage.com/index.html` with what page you want. Remember, this is the old http, not the new https:

`<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwebpage.com/index.html&amp;width&amp;layout=box_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=true&amp;height=65" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>`

or

`<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://webpage.com/index.html" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true"</div>`

or

`<span class='fb-like' data-href='http://webpage.com/index.html' data-layout='button_count' data-action='like' data-size='small' data-show-faces='false' data-share='false'></span>`